# Adding to a list removes from another list

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am very new to coding and asp.net.
I am creating a web application as part of course work.  The application allows users to create causes and sign other causes.  The problem I am having is that when a user signs a second cause their name is removed from the first cause.  I hope this makes sense and I would appreciate any help

This is the model for my cause.  The Cause has a list that will hold the users and is displayed to other users.

```
[Key]
public int CauseId { get; set; }
[Required(ErrorMessage = "A Title is required")]
[StringLength(160)]
public string Title { get; set; }
public int UserId { get; set; }
[DisplayName("Category")]
[Required(ErrorMessage = "A Category is required")]
public string Genre { get; set; }
[DisplayName("Created by")]
public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
[ScaffoldColumn(false)]
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd MMM yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
[DisplayName("Created on")]
public DateTime CreatedTime { get; set; }
[Required(ErrorMessage = "A Description is required")]
[StringLength(10000, MinimumLength = 1)]
[DisplayName("Description")]
public string Description { get; set; }
[Required(ErrorMessage = "A Target is required")]
[Range(10, 1000, ErrorMessage = "Target Signatures must be between 10 and 1000")]
public int Target { get; set; }
public virtual ICollection<SiteUser> Signatures { get; set; }
[DisplayName("No. of Signatures")]
public int SignatureCount { get; set; }
[DisplayName("Cause Image")]
[StringLength(1024)]
public string CauseImageUrl { get; set; }
public string Image { get; set; }
```

This is the model for my user

```
public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Username { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }
        [DisplayName("User Image")]
        public string UserImageUrl { get; set; }
```

This is the method I am using for the user to sign the cause

```
public JsonResult Sign(int? id)
        {
            var result = "Fail";
            if(id == null)
            {
                Response.StatusCode = 400;
                 result = "Bad Request, check input";
                return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
            if (Session["UserID"]  == null)
            {
                Response.StatusCode = 403;
                result = "Access forbidden";
                return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }

            Cause cause = db.Causes.Find(id);
            int memberID = Convert.ToInt32(Session["UserID"].ToString());
            SiteUser user = db.SiteUsers.Find(memberID);

            cause.Signatures.Add(user);

            db.SaveChanges();
            Response.StatusCode = 200;
            result = "Thanks for signing this cause";
            return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Code the details view

```
    @model Coursework.Models.Cause

    @{ ViewBag.Title = "Details";}
    <div class="bg"></div>
    <div class="jumbotron" style="height:200px; background-image: url(@Model.CauseImageUrl);">
        <h2 class="text-light bg-dark display-1">@Model.Title</h2>
    </div>


    <div class="container my-5">

        <div class="row ">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-4">
                        <h5>Category:</h5>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Genre)
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-4">
                        <h5>
                            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.CreatedBy):
                        </h5>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.CreatedBy)
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-4">
                        <h5>
                            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.CreatedTime):
                        </h5>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.CreatedTime)
                    </div>
                </div>
                <hr />
                <div class="row">
                </div>
                <h5>Description:</h5>
                <p>@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Description)</p>
            </div>

            <div class="container col-md-6">
                <h5>
                    Target number of signatures: @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Target)
                </h5>
                <div class="progress my-2">
                    <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped progress-bar-animated" id="progressBar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="7" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-12">
                        @{
                            Html.RenderPartial("_Sign", Model);
                        }
                        <div class='signMessage' id='addSignBtn'>Click here to sign</div>
                        <div id="socialMedia">
                            <a href="#" class="fab fa-facebook fa-3x"></a>
                            <a href="#" class="fab fa-twitter fa-3x"></a>
                            <a href="#" class="fab fa-linkedin fa-3x"></a>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script>

    //Add edit button
    $('#addEditBtn').append(' @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = Model.CauseId }, new { @class = "btn btn-outline-secondary" })');
    $('#addLoginBtn').append('<button type="button" class="btn btn-success mr-2 my-2" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" style="cursor:pointer" id="loginBtn">Sign</button>');
    $('#addSignBtn').append('<button type="button" class="btn btn-success ml-2" style="cursor:pointer" id="signbtn">Sign</button>');
    //update progress bar
    var progressBar = $('#progressBar');
    var progressIncrease = 1/@Model.Target * 100;
    var progressWidth = @Model.SignatureCount * progressIncrease;
    progressBar.width(progressWidth + "%");


    var signaturesTable = $('#signatures');
    var $signbtn = $('#signbtn');

    //hide thanks message
    $('#signSuccess').hide();


    //hide sign button if user created this and show edit

    $signbtn.on('click', function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var data = @Model.CauseId.ToString();

        $.ajax({
            type: "post",
            data: data,
            url: "/Causes/Sign/@Model.CauseId",
            success: function (result) {
                if (result = "Thanks for signing this cause") {
                    $('#signSuccessText').text(result);
                     progressBar.width(progressWidth + progressIncrease + "%");
                     $('#signatures').append('<tr><td><img src="@Session["UserImage"]" width="50px"</td><td>@Session["Username"]</td></tr>');
                    $('#signbtn').fadeOut(500);
                    $('#addSignBtn').fadeOut(500);
                    $('#signSuccess').fadeIn(500);
                    $('#noSigns').hide();
                    $('#signCount').text(@Model.SignatureCount + 1);

                }

            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

And the partial view

```
@model Coursework.Models.Cause
<h5>Signatures: <span class="badge badge-success" id="signCount">@Model.SignatureCount</span></h5>
<table id="signatures" class="col-sm-12 table table-striped">
    <th>
        User Image
    </th>
    <th>
        Name
    </th>
    @foreach (var x in Model.Signatures)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                <img style="width:50px" src="@x.UserImageUrl" alt="user image" />
            </td>
            <td>@x.Username</td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>
@if (Model.Signatures.Count < 1)
{
<div id="noSigns">
    <h6>No signatures yet, be the first</h6>
</div>
}
<div>
    @Html.Raw(ViewBag.signed)
</div>
<div id="signSuccess" class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible">
    <a id="linkClose" class="close" href="#" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</a>
    <div id="signSuccessText">Thanks for signing!</div>
</div>
```

Comment: the code here only adds a user to a cause. I don't see any code which would remove them. Are you actually seeing records disappearing from the database? That sounds unlikely, based on this. Or do you maybe just have an issue somewhere else in the code? Perhaps you have a view which is meant to display all the causes a user signed up for, but which has a bug and only displays the most recent one? I'm speculating, but that sounds far more likely than a problem with the code you've shown us.

Comment: When I view the SQL Server Object explorer the Signatures list is not there, so cant see if the data is in the database.

Comment: You're using SSMS to view it, I assume? The only cases I can think of for that are either somehow your user account doesn't have permission to the table, or you added it recently and haven't refreshed your object list, or you're looking in the wrong copy of the database

Comment: Of course you could just open a new query window in your database and write a SELECT statement manually to get the contents of the table. You're not obliged to use the GUI

Comment: Thanks, I have tired that and it looks like a column has been added to the SiteUsers table called Cause_CauseId and that is updated when the sign button is pressed. Any ideas why this is happening? ID Username Email Password UserImageUrl Cause_CauseId
1 Username1 user1@email.com Password1 /Images/generic-user-icon-19.jpg NULL
2 Username2 user2@email.com Password1 /Images/generic-user-icon-19.jpg 1

Comment: Are you using Entity Framework Code First? I don't really know how that tool works, but it sounds like your model is wrong. From a purely SQL point of view, I'd expect you to have 3 tables - because you should be modelling a many-to-many relationship. There should be a Causes table, a SiteUsers table and a Signatures table. Signatures should contain CauseID and UserID, with foreign keys back to the Causes and SiteUsers tables respectively. There should be no direct relationship between Causes and SiteUsers, only via the Signatures table.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help!